# NVidia: How to underclock the GPU and have it stick through reboots?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, gpu

I'd like to lower the clock of the GPU in my server. I have the GT420 installed, a small GPU with an even smaller radiator, which is noticeably turning even when no screen is connected. To deal wth this, I'd like to lower the clock speed or even deactivate the card entirely while no screen is connected. I've installed the appropriate NVidia driver already, but I find it hard to  apply existing tutorials on how to do this, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would it be better to remove *"and have it stick through reboots"* from the title unless you find out it doesn't stick? Having something "stick through reboots" is a question of itself and the answer is generally `cron @reboot`, Startup Applications, `rc.local`, etc.